# I want to add a new value to a key that is already associated with values in a dictionary in python

Tags: python

So I have a dictionary with keys and values. I am trying to add more values to an already existing key in a dictionary as efficiently as possible. I do not want to replace the key, I want to add to it on the end. Any help is appreciated.

```py
my_dictionary = {1: {'a', 'b'}, 2: {'c'}, 3: {'e', 'f'}}
my_dictionary[1] = my_dictionary[1].append('d')
```

**Expected Output** `my_dictionary = {1: {'a', 'b'}, 2: {'c', 'd'}, 3: {'e', 'f'}}`

I am aware that a dictionary does not have an append function, I just put it there to illustrate the process I would like to complete. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using sets as the values in your dictionary. You can add new values like so

```py
my_dictionary[1] = my_dictionary.get(1, set()).union({'d'})
```

`get` will return the set if the key (in this case 1) exists, if not it'll return an empty set. Either way you union what's returned with the set `{'d'}` and then store it back for with the key (again in this case 1)

You can do a similar thing with lists instead of sets like so

```py
my_dictionary[1] = my_dictionary.get(1, list()) + ['d']
```

Comment: note that since we inserted for key 1, the output will be `my_dictionary = {1: {'a', 'b', 'd'}, 2: {'c'}, 3: {'e', 'f'}}`. If you wanted to insert it to key `2`, then use that instead of `1`

Comment: Oh whoops, I thought it was zero indexed, but it makes sense as to why it is not. Sorry about that! I will try your solution and see what I get.

Comment: Dictionaries are not indexed! To access elements you you the keys...I suggest looking up some tutorial on the topic

Comment: Yes they are new to me an quite tricky, but I am starting to get the hang of them! Thank you for the clarification.

Answer (score 1):

Actually the key values are sets. And also `my_dictionary[1]` refers to the first key. So add values to sets using `.add()`:

```
my_dictionary = {1: {'a', 'b'}, 2: {'c'}, 3: {'e', 'f'}}
my_dictionary[2].add('d')
print(my_dictionary)
```